# Transport endpoint is not connected in SSHFS

Tags: ssh, sshfs

After reinstalling the server I can not mount it:

```
sshfs root@example.com:/var /remote_mount
fuse: bad mount point `/remote_mount': Transport endpoint is not connected
```

When I SSH, I get an error:

```
# ssh root@example.com
The authenticity of host 'example.com (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is 57:b6:bd:76:17:80:73:85:4a:14:8a:6f:dc:fa:fe:7c.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

Comment: Post output of  `ssh -v root@domain.com`?

Comment: question updated..

Comment: Type `yes` and try again.

Comment: @BAR, after I did `ssh root@domain.com` I deleted the old RSA key and now it works again.. (The server got a new IP address) Create an answer :)

Comment: Good to know it worked for you!

Comment: Same error here, but `ssh user@domain.com` works flawlessly, so sshd seems to be set up properly. Any ideas?

Answer (score 63):

This error popped up for me after I had been using sshfs on and off for years. A search found this page but all the "setup sshd" answers were not much help as sshfs had been working well until it suddenly didn't and ssh worked just fine to other locations.

However, after a bit of frustrating poking and testing I found the solution. The problem started with a sshfs mount failing from a bad hostname in it. As `ls -l $mountpoint` failed with this error I tried clearing the trouble with `fusermount -u $mountpoint`, and the mount started to work again!

Even a simple `ls $mountpoint` made the error after the failed sshfs.

Comment: That was the problem here too.

Comment: This helped.. but first I had to kill a process that had the mount point open `lsof | grep $mountpoint`

Comment: @jsj that can be a good point.

Answer (score 31):

I had this problem after using sshfs for some time. This answer is relevant only for situations where sshfs was already used successfully prior to the problem.

What usually causes this problem is that you terminated the connection sometime ago, and the system still has the `/remote_mount` mounted. First try doing:

```
sudo umount /remote_mount
```

and then attempt to connect again.

Comment: Why was this downvoted? That made it for me, thank U !!

Comment: This answer was the right one for me too

Comment: This makes sense and worked for me, I got the same error when clicking the mounted directory in Nautilus "Files" Browser. I ran the umount command and it reset the state so it could be mounted again!

Comment: Great answer. Thanks !

Comment: This is resonable and correct i think

Comment: umount: /remote_mount: target is busy